# Share on Linkedin in Objective c based on new LInkedin API (Not a que)

Tags: share, linkedin-api

set share permission  `w_share` while login.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".../oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&state=svhgktyjuid&scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+w_share",linked_in_api_key,call_back_url];

- (void)shareImp
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"share This on Linkedin"];

    NSMutableDictionary *contentDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [contentDic setValue:logoURL forKey:@"submitted-image-url"];
    [contentDic setValue:@"https://itunes.apple.com/..." forKey:@"submitted-url"];
    [contentDic setValue:message forKey:@"title"];

     NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [[NSDictionary alloc]
                             initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have a new APP! And I got it in a snap!"] ,@"comment",contentDic,@"content",nil];

    NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json&oauth2_access_token=%@",_accessToken]];

     NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    //allocate a new operation queue

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    //Loads the data for a URL request and executes a handler block on an
    //operation queue when the request completes or fails.

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"response...%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

     }];
}
```

Thank you..Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot :: @Marko

Comment: You are welcome @Sommm. Iphone development is not my field... but I suggest you to better explain what happens / goes wrong, since it may be unclear. Another plus of this is, that your question will go to the top of the list again, so people could see it again. Hope your question gets answered!